# Chrome tab crash with online graphs

Tags: jquery, crash, d3.js

I'm developing a website where I have graphs that are updated about every 5 seconds (inline graphs). The problem is that chrome tab crashes after about 30-40 minutes of working.
I don't know what's the problem and I couldn't find a way to get logs of chrome crashes.

What I did find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome/8040153#8040153) thread saying that when chrome tab is not in focus it doesn't update the view and when it gets back to focus it makes all the updates it didn't make which might cause a crash. I guess it might be my problem as well. The problem is that the solution suggested there is clearing jquery animation, however I use d3.js for the graphs. Any suggestions on how I can achieve the same thing with d3.js?

Comment: It's impossible to tell what's going on without some additional information. My guess is that the amount of data becomes so large that Chrome runs out of memory or processing the data takes so long that it decides that the script is hung.

Comment: I use the timeline of chrome and it seems like the memory is OK and processing the data doesn't take long.